# SharePoint 2013: Collapsing subtasks by default in a Gantt Chart

Tags: 2013, gantt-view

I was wondering if I could create a script that would modify the current Gantt Chart view so that all of the subtasks would be collapsed. I got the idea from this post which does this on a list: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/51a1ada6-d514-4727-b9a5-6a689b70067e/tasks-with-subtasks-collapse-by-default-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

I tried implementing their codes on the Gantt chart to no avail. Eventually I would also like to make custom views with certain subtasks collapsed and other subtasks expanded. Is any of this possible?

Thank you so much!